# How to get TextView in Activity from current ViewPager view

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm new to Android development. For learning purpose, I'm trying to create a swipable carousel-like thing. I'm doing that with the help of ViewPager and then using a PagerAdapter.

I'm populating the views with the JSON data, and it's working fine. Having no issues with loading and showing data with JSON. The problem is the Null Pointer Exception I'm getting when I'm trying to grab the data of the current View in my Carousel Activity.

I want to copy/toast the data from the current view in my viewpager. For that matter, I'm trying to get the current view and then the concerned textview with `findViewById()`, but it throws the null pointer exception.

I've even tried `findViewWithTag()`, but again, it failed. Some research on the same told me that you have to get the textview in the Adapter class only, with the help of inflated view. I'm not getting it completely though.

The below given is my CarouselAdapter.java file:

```
public class CarouselAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
  Context context;
  public static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
  List<CarouselModel> result;

  public CarouselAdapter(CarouselPage carouselPage, List<CarouselModel> contentData) {
    result=contentData;
    context= carouselPage;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  public class SlideHolder {
    TextView description;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return this.result.size();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    SlideHolder holder = new SlideHolder();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_adapter,container,false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);

    holder.description = tv;

    holder.description.setText(result.get(position).getDescription());

    container.addView(view);
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
  }
}
```

It also makes use of a Model class, which goes like below:

```
public class CarouselModel {
  String description;

  public CarouselModel(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

Now in my CarouselActivity.java, I have things going on like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.carousel_page);

  content = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

  cNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.carousel_next);
  cPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.carousel_prev);

  // This button creates problem, and returns the null pointer error
  cCopyButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.carousel_copy);

  // This function loads up data from JSON to show in different views, and it works fine
  retrieveJSON();

  content.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListener);

  tv = content.findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);

  cNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      content.setCurrentItem(cCurrentPage + 1);
    }
  });

  cPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      content.setCurrentItem(cCurrentPage - 1);
    }
  });

  cCopyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text is " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      toast.show();
    }
  });
}

private void retrieveJSON() {
  ....
}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int j) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    cCurrentPage = i;

    //Have also tried this logic, but it returned null pointer error again
    //View view = content.getRootView();
    //tv = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);

    if(i == 0) {
      cNextButton.setEnabled(true);
      cPrevButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(i == content.getChildCount()) {
      cNextButton.setEnabled(false);
      cPrevButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
      cNextButton.setEnabled(true);
      cPrevButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
  }
};
```

Could anyone please point out what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: How are you adding pages to pager , add that code as wel

Comment: carousel_copy button should be a part of the carousel_page layout. Please post your layout files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by two way.

1. Using `Interface`.
   By using Interface you have to create a method like `onGetText(String text)` . this text indicate that you want to set this text in TextView that located in Activity (Assume that the activity is alive). So implement the interface in your Activity and call interface method when viewpager`s page changed

**Note:** I just give an example that you want to pass only text. But you can pass other things if you want.

Example code:

```
public interface Communicator{
  void onGetText(String text);
}
```

In your activity:

```
class CarouselActivity implements Communicator{
  .....

  @Override
  void onGetText(String text){
  // You have activity so now access your textView
}
}
```

You have to init the interface:

```
viewPgaerAdapter.init(this);
```

Last changes in your view pager:

```
private Communicator callback;

public void init(Communicator c){
  callback = c;
}

....
@Override
onPageSelected(...){
 if(callback!=null){
  callback.onGetText(yourText);
}
}
```

2. Using **Activity instance**.  You have to pass Context of Activity in your view pager. and also TextView of Activity must be public. then `((ActivityName)mContext)publicTextViewOfActivity`

mContext is the context that you pass.

I think you will get some idea.

Comment: your first method is fine, though more some explanation needed

Comment: in your first method cant get text when viewPager position is 0

Answer (score 0):

you can add method to your adapter which returns currently selected `CarouselModel` using `cCurrentPosition`

it would look like this

```
public CarouselModel getItem(Integer position) {
    return result.get(position)
}
```

I assumed that you are creating adapter instance in your activity, in that case save adapter's instance, and modify activity's code:

```
 cCopyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     String msg = mPagerAdapter.getItem(cCurrentPosition);
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text is " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     toast.show();
}
```

});